# Handling Windows 8 lifecycle

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, lifecycle

i have run into a problem, that my app sometimes Activates and sometimes Launches when i open something via:

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = false;
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(sampleFile, options);
```

When app re-activates it shows the same window - when i went to an external app using LaunchFileAsync - this is nice.

But sometimes the app launches, i see a SplashPage and app is beginning from the MainPage. - how can i make this also to return to the page, that i left when used LaunchFileAsync?

**Example:**

I have a MainPage and a BlankPage1

So here is my page on suspend+shutdown (terminate) 8 buttons:

[image]

On Restore 0 buttons, **I WANT TO SAVE MY VIEW XAML CODE** when app gets killed by system:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the conditions of your application shutdown. Was it suspended and terminated automatically by the OS ? or did you close it yourself ? (ex : ALT-F4)

You can see here the application lifecyle : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx

If you want your application to restore its previous state on a user shutdown, I think you can enable it on your OnLaunched method in you App.xaml.cs :

```cs
if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated
                || args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.ClosedByUser)
{
    try
    {
        await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
    }
    catch (SuspensionManagerException)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, if your Page extends LayoutAwarePage, you have two methods, SaveState and LoadState.
These methods are called automatically when navigating from or to the frame (including suspending/restoring/opening...).

If you save your data behind your buttons in your SaveState method, you can restore it in the LoadState method (and thus redraw your buttons). There is a detailled exemple here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx

Comment: I have managed to restore frame and data that was in code-behind. But, all Views, User controls that were in the moment of app closing - haven't been saved. How can i acomplish this?
Lets say, i have a button, that creates a button in a stack panel. On app shutdown i had 10 buttons in a stack, but when i Restored it - it doesn;t have any